# Watch Log for "Success" or "Failed" string using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do everything I would have previously used Bash for in Python, in order to finally learn the language. However, this problem has me stumped, and I haven't been able to find any solutions fitting my use-case.

There is an element of trying to run before I can walk with though, so I'm looking for some direction.

**Here's the issue:**

I have a Python script that starts a separate program that creates and writes to a log file.

I want to watch that log file, and print out "Successful Run" if the script detects the "Success" string in the log, and "Failed Run" if the "Failed" string is found instead. The underlying process generally takes about 10 seconds to get to the stage where it'll write "Success" or "Failure" to the log file. Neither string will appear in the log at the same. It's either a success, or failure. It can't be both.

I've been attempting to do this with a while loop. So I can continue to watch the log file, until the string appears, and then exit when it does. I have got it working for just one string, but I'm unsure how to accomodate the other string.

Here's the code I'm running.

```py
log_path = "test.log"
success = "Success"
failure = "Failed"

with open(log_path) as log:
    while success != True:
        if success in log.read():
            print("Process Successfully Completed")
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Save your `log.read()` in a variable and then you can use it for more than one test. By the way, you should put some kind of sleep into that loop.

Comment: `success` will never be `True`, since you are not changing it. So `while True` instead of `while success != True` will be better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers above from alaniwi and David, I've actually managed to get it to work, using the following code. So I must have been quite close originally.

I've wrapped it all in a `while True`, put the `log.read()` into a variable, and added an `elif`. Definitely interested in any pointers on whether this is the most Pythonic way to do it though? So please critique if need be.

```py
    while True:
        with open(log_path) as log:

            read_log = log.read()

            if success in read_log:
                print("Process Successfully Completed")
                sys.exit()

            elif fail in read_log:
                print("Failed")
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: You can use [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) to check for the *modified time* of that file rather than reading the whole file at once every iteration. Also it might be good to include some [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to increase the polling interval. Finally you can use regex ([`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) in order to parse the content only once; something like `match = re.search('Success|Fail', read_log); if match is not None and match.group(0) == 'Success': ...`.

Comment: Thanks @a_guest appreciate your reply, I'll give those tips a try as well.